# Contract address returning as undefined in console

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

var accounts_list = web3.eth.accounts;
var code = fs.readFileSync('Voting.sol').toString();
var compiledCode = solc.compile(code);
var abiDefinition = JSON.parse(compiledCode.contracts[':Voting'].interface)
var VotingContract = web3.eth.contract(abiDefinition)
var byteCode = compiledCode.contracts[':Voting'].bytecode
var deployedContract = VotingContract.new(['Itachi','Luffy','Midoriya'],{data: byteCode, from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4700000})
var deployedContractAddress = deployedContract.address;

var contractInstance = VotingContract.at(deployedContract.address);
// contractInstance.voteForCandidate('Itachi', {from: web3.eth.accounts[0]}) // function to vote for Itachi
// contractInstance.totalVotesFor.call('Itachi').toLocaleString() // function to return Itachi's votes

var deployedAddress = contractInstance.address;

console.log(contractInstance.address);
```

the ouput is: `undefined`

but when i manually run each command on node Console it is not the case.
when i tried `typeof contractInstance.address` it outputs as "String"

but i dont want to run each command manually every time
hence tried running it in a script

Comment: I believe `VotingContract.new` returns a `Promise`, and you have to wait until that promise is resolved before you'll have an address.

Comment: how to do that i tried putting all the code except console part in a function.
then used promise to call print..still didn't work

Comment: Actually, what version of web3.js are you using?

Comment: web3 verison: ^0.20.1

Comment: its working fine when i do it in  console..but when i run it as a script  it shows undefined..so version might not be the problem
It may have to do something with Promises

Comment: That version doesn't use `Promises`, so you can ignore that.

Comment: ya ok..but still how to get the address

Comment: i tried this: 


`function first() {
 var deployedContract = VotingContract.new(['Itachi','Luffy','Midoriya'],{data: byteCode, from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4700000})
 return deployedContract
}

var promise = first();

promise.then(function(data){
 var deployedContractAddress = deployedContract.address;
    var contractInstance = VotingContract.at(deployedContract.address);
    console.log(contractInstance.address)
})`

but it returns that: `promise.then is not a function`

Comment: Yeah, as I said, the version of web3.js you're using doesn't return `Promise`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract), if you deploy the contract synchronously, the function returns immediately with a transaction hash, but you'll need to poll the transaction's status until it's mined. (Only then will the contract's address be available.)

As an alternative, you can deploy the contract asynchronously:

```
VotingContract.new(['Itachi','Luffy','Midoriya'],{data: byteCode, from: web3.eth.accounts[0], gas: 4700000}, function (err, deployedContract) {
    if (deployedContract.address) {
        console.log(`Address: ${deployedContract.address}`);
        // use deployedContract here
    }
});
```